# Why does printf show an additional % character in the terminal?

Tags: c

I started learning to code with the C language. I wrote the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int count = 0;

    printf("Count %d.", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile and run the program, the data is printed:

```
Count 0.%
```

But if I fix the line `printf("Count %d.", count);` into `printf("Count %d.\n", count);`, just adding `\n` after `Count %d.`, then the data printed is:

```
Count 0.
```

Comment: Where do you run it? Is the % your shell prompt?

Comment: Are you actually compiling this on your computer? Or using one of those in browser compilers on learning/tutorial websites?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, I run on the terminal of the Mac with gcc.

Comment: `%` comes from your shell prompt. Try to run your program and redirect the output to a file. For example, if you named your program `main` : `./main > test.txt`. See, `%` is not in the file. Or you can reproduce the behavior with this simple command `echo -n 'toto'`

Comment: At your shell, just hit "enter" a few times.  You should get a new line with a `%` prompt each time.  The `%` has nothing to do with your program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your shell is likely adding a `%` sign to indicate that the line was not properly terminated (no newline character was printed at the end of the line). Some shells do this: for example, ZSH shows `%` and fish shell shows `⏎`. ZSH should also be the default shell on macOS.

Just add `\n` to the format string passed to `printf()` and you're good.

Comment: It is unlikely a naîve user changed their shell from the default. The reported behavior is more likely just the prompt from the default shell.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Either way, the solution is the same.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what does that mean? Installing a new shell is very easy. They could also be using a preconfigured/precustomized computer, and we don't even know the exact operating system they are using. This is the only sensible answer to the question.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Whether installing a shell is easy or not or whether they could be using a preconfigured computer or not is irrelevant. My comment says it is **unlikely** a naîve user changed (not installed) their shell from the default, not that it is **difficult** to change a shell. As noted in my comment and by others above, this is not the only sensible answer. The “%” may be the shell command prompt, not a marker added by the shell to mark a missing newline character.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if that was the case the user wouldn't have said: "*down rows(not see) already replaced %?*"...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: That text is incomprehensible, and its meaning and cause are unclear.

Comment: Hi @MarcoBonelli

It's true that I'm using ZSH. That's because the warning shell type is not the printf function that caused the problem.
Thank you for giving me information.

Answer (score 2):

Like Bonelli said, by showing with a `%` character `zsh` implies that the output has an unterminated line.

Meanwhile, zsh also lets you disable that feature by:

`set +o prompt_cr +o prompt_sp`

But the next prompt will show just right after the output(at the same line).

You can also change that mark with the $PROMPT_EOL_MARK variable.